# How do I check whether a fuse folder is present

Tags: php, fuse, sshfs

I have a folder mounted on the server that points to an sftp site.
I need to check via php whether we can see the folders inside it.

I tried

```
file_exists("/path/to/the/mount/folder");
```

but its returning false (which I kind of expected), I can navigate to it through the file system and using terminal.

(also tried `is_dir` && `is_link`)

Here's how I mounted it from the shell

```
echo PASS | sshfs UNAME@URL: /path/goes/here -o password_stdin
```

Comment: If it's mounted ont the FS, then it should be same as if it was normal directory - the OS with abstract away the fact its SFTP. `is_dir` will tell you if it's a readable directory. Probably you don't have permissions to open it from PHP (eg apache user, if the apache is running your php through mod_php)?

Comment: that's a possibility - Ill check

Comment: Im unable to change permissions or owner even as root, I may need to look at how I mounted it again

Comment: @Veseliq thanks you really deserve the credit for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Also when having similar problem one should check webserver configuration (apache2 or other that you use) for access restrictions (like open_basedir in apache2). This was my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a configuration problem.

In `/etc/fuse.conf` I uncommented `user_allow_other`

Then mounted with this command

```
echo PASS | sshfs UNAME@URL: /path/goes/here -o password_stdin,allow_other
```

Normal file/folder checking/reading functions will then work fine

Answer (score 0):

The path should be a string, so:

```
is_dir("/path/to/the/mount/folder");
```

Also, if it's unix based I always forget that it's case sensitive :P

Comment: It is I just replaced it and I would have seen the error thrown from the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$path = "/path/to/the/folder";
$name_of_files = glob($path, "*.*");
foreach($name_of_file as $filename)
{
echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: I know how to use glob and various other ways to check standard file folder or link presence. This doesn't help at all